# Strange clash label positioning pgfkeys

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I have a couple of macros using pgfkeys, kindly written by a friend (I am unfortunately no expert in this advanced pgf/tikz coding).

One of the macro draws a couple of squares with a path between them, every parameter being very flexible and customizable.

```
\makeatletter

% Setup keys for square macro.
% Used to specify:
% - Labels for arrows.
% - Styles for labels and arrows.

\def\labelstylecodes#1{%
  \pgfkeys@split@path%
  \edef\label@key{/square/label/\pgfkeyscurrentname}%
  \edef\style@key{\pgfkeyscurrentkey/.@val}%
  \def\temp@a{#1}%
  \def\temp@b{\pgfkeysnovalue}%
  \ifx\temp@a\temp@b
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{\label@key}\temp@a
    \ifx\temp@a\temp@b\else
      \pgfkeysalso{commutative diagrams/.cd, \style@key}%
    \fi
  \else
    \pgfkeys{\style@key/.code = \pgfkeysalso{#1}}%
  \fi}
\def\arrowstylecodes#1{%
  \edef\style@key{\pgfkeyscurrentkey/.@val}%
  \def\temp@a{#1}%
  \def\temp@b{\pgfkeysnovalue}%
  \ifx\temp@a\temp@b
    \pgfkeysalso{commutative diagrams/.cd, \style@key}%
  \else
    \pgfkeys{\style@key/.code = \pgfkeysalso{#1}}%
  \fi}

% Don't change these defaults here. These can be changed locally in the
% key-value list provided in a call to the morphism of squares macro.

\pgfkeys{
  /square/label/.cd,
  0/.initial = {$\bullet$}, 1/.initial = {$\bullet$}, 2/.initial = {$\bullet$},
  3/.initial = {$\bullet$},
  01/.initial, 12/.initial, 23/.initial,
  02/.initial, 03/.initial, 13/.initial,
  012/.initial, 013/.initial, 023/.initial, 123/.initial,
  0123/.initial,
  /square/labelstyle/.cd,
  01/.@val/.initial, 12/.@val/.initial, 23/.@val/.initial,
  03/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap},
  02/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{description},
  13/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{description},
  012/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{below left = -1pt and -1pt},
  013/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap, right},
  023/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{left},
  123/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap, below right = -1pt and -1pt},
  0123/.@val/.initial,
  01/.code=\labelstylecodes{#1}, 02/.code=\labelstylecodes{#1},
  03/.code=\labelstylecodes{#1}, 12/.code=\labelstylecodes{#1},
  13/.code=\labelstylecodes{#1}, 23/.code=\labelstylecodes{#1},
  012/.code=\labelstylecodes{#1}, 013/.code=\labelstylecodes{#1},
  023/.code=\labelstylecodes{#1}, 123/.code=\labelstylecodes{#1},
  0123/.code=\labelstylecodes{#1},
  /square/arrowstyle/.cd,
  01/.@val/.initial, 12/.@val/.initial, 23/.@val/.initial,
  02/.@val/.initial, 03/.@val/.initial, 13/.@val/.initial,
  012/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  013/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  023/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  123/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  0123/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{triple},
  01/.code=\arrowstylecodes{#1}, 02/.code=\arrowstylecodes{#1},
  03/.code=\arrowstylecodes{#1}, 12/.code=\arrowstylecodes{#1},
  13/.code=\arrowstylecodes{#1}, 23/.code=\arrowstylecodes{#1},
  012/.code=\arrowstylecodes{#1}, 013/.code=\arrowstylecodes{#1},
  023/.code=\arrowstylecodes{#1}, 123/.code=\arrowstylecodes{#1},
  0123/.code=\arrowstylecodes{#1}
}

% Macros to draw 2-cells.

\def\sq@abc{%
  \draw [/square/arrowstyle/012] (126:0.25) --
  node [/square/labelstyle/012] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/square/label/012}} (126:0.6);
}
\def\sq@bcd{%
  \draw [/square/arrowstyle/123] (54:0.25) --
  node [/square/labelstyle/123] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/square/label/123}} (54:0.6);
}
\def\sq@acd{%
  \draw [/square/arrowstyle/023] (-55:0.55) --
  node [/square/labelstyle/023] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/square/label/023}} (-15:0.4);
}
\def\sq@abd{%
  \draw [/square/arrowstyle/013] (235:0.55) --
  node [/square/labelstyle/013] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/square/label/013}} (195:0.4);
}


% Macro to draw a single square node.

\def\sq@#1#2{
  \begin{scope}[shift=#2, commutative diagrams/every diagram]

    \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3} {
      \tikzmath{\a = 225 - (90 * \i);}
      \node (n{#1}\i) at (\a:1) {
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/square/label/\i}};
    }

    \node (s#1) at (0,0) [circle, inner sep = 0pt,
    fit = (n{#1}0.center)(n{#1}1.center)(n{#1}2.center)
          (n{#1}3.center)] {};

    \begin{scope}[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow, every label]
      \ifcase #1
      \def\list{0/1, 1/2, 2/3, 0/2, 0/3}\or
      \def\list{0/1, 1/2, 2/3, 1/3, 0/3}\else
      \def\list{}\fi

      \foreach \s / \e in \list {
        \draw [/square/arrowstyle/\s\e] (n{#1}\s) --
          node [/square/labelstyle/\s\e] {
          \pgfkeysvalueof{/square/label/\s\e}} (n{#1}\e);
      }

      \ifcase #1
      \sq@abc\sq@acd\or
      \sq@abd\sq@bcd
      \else\fi

    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
}

% The 3-simplex macro itself.
%
% This is the only user callable macro provided here.
%
% Takes a single parameter consisting of a list of key value pairs. These are
% processed using the keys mechanism (pgfkeys) built into TikZ, so they follow
% a familiar format.
%
% /square/label/XXX = ....      Set code to typeset label of arrow XXX
% /square/arrowstyle/XXX = ...  Set TikZ format for typesetting of arrow XXX.
%                                 Overrides default.
% /square/labelstyle/XXX = ...  Set TikZ format for typesetting of label on
%                                 arrow XXX. Overrides default.
%
% Here XXX denotes a sequence of integers identifying a generating cell by
% listing the numbers of the vertices (in order) of the corresponding face of
% the 4-simplex.
%
% You may use the path setting mechanism of pgfkeys to avoid too much path noise
% in a key value list. For example:
%
%   \square{/square/label/.cd,
%     0=$0$, 1=$1$, 2=$2$, 3=$3$,
%     01=$a$, 12=$b$, 23=$c$, 02=$f$, 03=$g$, 13=$h$,
%     012=$\alpha$, 023=$\beta$, 123=$\gamma$, 013=$\delta$,
%     0123=$\mathcal{F}$}
%

\def\square#1{
  \pgfkeys{#1}
  \sq@{0}{(180:1.8)}\sq@{1}{(0:1.8)}

  \begin{scope}[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow, every label]
    \draw [shorten >=10pt, shorten <=10pt, /square/arrowstyle/0123] (s0) --
    node [/square/labelstyle/0123] {
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/square/label/0123}} (s1);

  \end{scope}
}

\makeatother
```

Putting the code above in a file square.tex, a MWE would be

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% Option, used to get squiggly arrows in example.
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\input{square}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.6, font=\footnotesize]
     \square{
        /square/label/.cd,
        01=$f$, 12=$g$, 23=$h$, 03=$i$, 02=$j$, 13=$k$,
        012=$\beta$, 023=$\alpha$, 123=$\delta$, 013=$\gamma$,
        0123=$\Gamma$,
        /square/arrowstyle/.cd,
        23={equal}, 01={squiggly},
        /square/labelstyle/.cd,
        03={swap, near end}
     }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have modified this to get a completely similar macro, just symmetric to the above. I shall refer to this as squares.

```
\makeatletter

% Setup keys for squares macro.
% Used to specify:
% - Labels for arrows.
% - Styles for labels and arrows.

\def\labelstylecode#1{%
  \pgfkeys@split@path%
  \edef\label@key{/squares/label/\pgfkeyscurrentname}%
  \edef\style@key{\pgfkeyscurrentkey/.@val}%
  \def\temp@a{#1}%
  \def\temp@b{\pgfkeysnovalue}%
  \ifx\temp@a\temp@b
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{\label@key}\temp@a
    \ifx\temp@a\temp@b\else
      \pgfkeysalso{commutative diagrams/.cd, \style@key}%
    \fi
  \else
    \pgfkeys{\style@key/.code = \pgfkeysalso{#1}}%
  \fi}
\def\arrowstylecode#1{%
  \edef\style@key{\pgfkeyscurrentkey/.@val}%
  \def\temp@a{#1}%
  \def\temp@b{\pgfkeysnovalue}%
  \ifx\temp@a\temp@b
    \pgfkeysalso{commutative diagrams/.cd, \style@key}%
  \else
    \pgfkeys{\style@key/.code = \pgfkeysalso{#1}}%
  \fi}

% Don't change these defaults here. These can be changed locally in the
% key-value list provided in a call to the morphism of squaress macro.

\pgfkeys{
  /squares/label/.cd,
  0/.initial = {$\bullet$}, 1/.initial = {$\bullet$}, 2/.initial = {$\bullet$},
  3/.initial = {$\bullet$},
  01/.initial, 12/.initial, 23/.initial,
  02/.initial, 03/.initial, 13/.initial,
  012/.initial, 013/.initial, 023/.initial, 123/.initial,
  0123/.initial,
  /squares/labelstyle/.cd,
  01/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap},
  12/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap},
  23/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap},
  03/.@val/.initial,
  02/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{description},
  13/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{description},
  012/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{above left = -1pt and -1pt},
  013/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap, right},
  023/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{left},
  123/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap, above right = -1pt and -1pt},
  0123/.@val/.initial,
  01/.code=\labelstylecode{#1}, 02/.code=\labelstylecode{#1},
  03/.code=\labelstylecode{#1}, 12/.code=\labelstylecode{#1},
  13/.code=\labelstylecode{#1}, 23/.code=\labelstylecode{#1},
  012/.code=\labelstylecode{#1}, 013/.code=\labelstylecode{#1},
  023/.code=\labelstylecode{#1}, 123/.code=\labelstylecode{#1},
  0123/.code=\labelstylecode{#1},
  /squares/arrowstyle/.cd,
  01/.@val/.initial, 12/.@val/.initial, 23/.@val/.initial,
  02/.@val/.initial, 03/.@val/.initial, 13/.@val/.initial,
  012/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  013/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  023/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  123/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  0123/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  01/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}, 02/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1},
  03/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}, 12/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1},
  13/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}, 23/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1},
  012/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}, 013/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1},
  023/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}, 123/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1},
  0123/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}
}

% Macros to draw 2-cells.

\def\sqs@abc{%
  \draw [/squares/arrowstyle/012] (235:0.25) --
  node [/squares/labelstyle/012] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/squares/label/012}} (235:0.6);
}
\def\sqs@bcd{%
  \draw [/squares/arrowstyle/123] (-54:0.25) --
  node [/squares/labelstyle/123] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/squares/label/123}} (-54:0.6);
}
\def\sqs@acd{%
  \draw [/squares/arrowstyle/023] (55:0.55) --
  node [/squares/labelstyle/023] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/squares/label/023}} (15:0.45);
}
\def\sqs@abd{%
  \draw [/squares/arrowstyle/013] (125:0.55) --
  node [/squares/labelstyle/013] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/squares/label/013}} (165:0.45);
}


% Macro to draw a single squares node.

\def\sqs@#1#2{
  \begin{scope}[shift=#2, commutative diagrams/every diagram]

    \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3} {
      \tikzmath{\a = 135 + (90 * \i);}
      \node (n{#1}\i) at (\a:1) {
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/squares/label/\i}};
    }

    \node (s#1) at (0,0) [circle, inner sep = 0pt,
    fit = (n{#1}0.center)(n{#1}1.center)(n{#1}2.center)
          (n{#1}3.center)] {};

    \begin{scope}[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow, every label]
      \ifcase #1
      \def\list{0/1, 1/2, 2/3, 0/2, 0/3}\or
      \def\list{0/1, 1/2, 2/3, 1/3, 0/3}\else
      \def\list{}\fi

      \foreach \s / \e in \list {
        \draw [/squares/arrowstyle/\s\e] (n{#1}\s) --
          node [/squares/labelstyle/\s\e] {
          \pgfkeysvalueof{/squares/label/\s\e}} (n{#1}\e);
      }

      \ifcase #1
      \sqs@abc\sqs@acd\or
      \sqs@abd\sqs@bcd
      \else\fi

    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
}

% The 3-simplex macro itself.
%
% This is the only user callable macro provided here.
%
% Takes a single parameter consisting of a list of key value pairs. These are
% processed using the keys mechanism (pgfkeys) built into TikZ, so they follow
% a familiar format.
%
% /squares/label/XXX = ....      Set code to typeset label of arrow XXX
% /squares/arrowstyle/XXX = ...  Set TikZ format for typesetting of arrow XXX.
%                                 Overrides default.
% /squares/labelstyle/XXX = ...  Set TikZ format for typesetting of label on
%                                 arrow XXX. Overrides default.
%
% Here XXX denotes a sequence of integers identifying a generating cell by
% listing the numbers of the vertices (in order) of the corresponding face of
% the 4-simplex.
%
% You may use the path setting mechanism of pgfkeys to avoid too much path noise
% in a key value list. For example:
%
%   \squares{/squares/label/.cd,
%     0=$0$, 1=$1$, 2=$2$, 3=$3$,
%     01=$a$, 12=$b$, 23=$c$, 02=$f$, 03=$g$, 13=$h$,
%     012=$\alpha$, 023=$\beta$, 123=$\gamma$, 013=$\delta$,
%     0123=$\mathcal{F}$}
%

\def\squares#1{
  \pgfkeys{#1}
  \sqs@{0}{(180:1.8)}\sqs@{1}{(0:1.8)}

  \begin{scope}[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow, every label]
    \draw [shorten >=10pt, shorten <=10pt, /squares/arrowstyle/0123] (s0) --
    node [/squares/labelstyle/0123] {%
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/squares/label/0123}} (s1);

  \end{scope}
}

\makeatother
```

No problem so far. There is a last macro, dealing with some iterated pentagon of pentagons. I call this file pent.tex.

```
\makeatletter

% Setup keys for pentagon macro.
% Used to specify:
% - Labels for arrows.
% - Styles for labels and arrows.

\def\labelstylecode#1{%
  \pgfkeys@split@path%
  \edef\label@key{/pentagon/label/\pgfkeyscurrentname}%
  \edef\style@key{\pgfkeyscurrentkey/.@val}%
  \def\temp@a{#1}%
  \def\temp@b{\pgfkeysnovalue}%
  \ifx\temp@a\temp@b
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{\label@key}\temp@a
    \ifx\temp@a\temp@b\else
      \pgfkeysalso{commutative diagrams/.cd, \style@key}%
    \fi
  \else
    \pgfkeys{\style@key/.code = \pgfkeysalso{#1}}%
  \fi}
\def\arrowstylecode#1{%
  \edef\style@key{\pgfkeyscurrentkey/.@val}%
  \def\temp@a{#1}%
  \def\temp@b{\pgfkeysnovalue}%
  \ifx\temp@a\temp@b
    \pgfkeysalso{commutative diagrams/.cd, \style@key}%
  \else
    \pgfkeys{\style@key/.code = \pgfkeysalso{#1}}%
  \fi}

% Don't change these defaults here. These can be changed locally in the
% key-value list provided in a call to the pentagon of pentagons macro.

\pgfkeys{
  /pentagon/label/.cd,
  0/.initial = {$\bullet$}, 1/.initial = {$\bullet$}, 2/.initial = {$\bullet$},
  3/.initial = {$\bullet$}, 4/.initial = {$\bullet$},
  01/.initial, 12/.initial, 23/.initial, 34/.initial, 04/.initial,
  02/.initial, 03/.initial, 13/.initial, 14/.initial, 24/.initial,
  012/.initial, 013/.initial, 014/.initial, 023/.initial, 024/.initial,
  034/.initial, 123/.initial, 124/.initial, 134/.initial, 234/.initial,
  0123/.initial, 0124/.initial, 0134/.initial, 0234/.initial, 1234/.initial,
  01234/.initial,
  /pentagon/labelstyle/.cd,
  01/.@val/.initial, 12/.@val/.initial, 23/.@val/.initial, 34/.@val/.initial,
  04/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap},
  02/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{description},
  03/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{description},
  13/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{description},
  14/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{description},
  24/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{description},
  012/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap, above},
  013/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{below = 1pt},
  014/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{below},
  023/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap, above = 1pt},
  024/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{below left = -1pt and -1pt},
  034/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap, right},
  123/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{below left = -1pt and -1pt},
  124/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap, right},
  134/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{left},
  234/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap, below right = -1pt and -1pt},
  0123/.@val/.initial,
  0124/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap},
  0134/.@val/.initial,
  0234/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap},
  1234/.@val/.initial,
  01234/.@val/.initial,
  01/.code=\labelstylecode{#1}, 02/.code=\labelstylecode{#1},
  03/.code=\labelstylecode{#1}, 04/.code=\labelstylecode{#1},
  12/.code=\labelstylecode{#1}, 13/.code=\labelstylecode{#1},
  14/.code=\labelstylecode{#1}, 23/.code=\labelstylecode{#1},
  24/.code=\labelstylecode{#1}, 34/.code=\labelstylecode{#1},
  012/.code=\labelstylecode{#1}, 013/.code=\labelstylecode{#1},
  014/.code=\labelstylecode{#1}, 023/.code=\labelstylecode{#1},
  024/.code=\labelstylecode{#1}, 034/.code=\labelstylecode{#1},
  123/.code=\labelstylecode{#1}, 124/.code=\labelstylecode{#1},
  134/.code=\labelstylecode{#1}, 234/.code=\labelstylecode{#1},
  0123/.code=\labelstylecode{#1}, 0124/.code=\labelstylecode{#1},
  0134/.code=\labelstylecode{#1}, 0234/.code=\labelstylecode{#1},
  1234/.code=\labelstylecode{#1}, 01234/.code=\labelstylecode{#1},
  /pentagon/arrowstyle/.cd,
  01/.@val/.initial, 12/.@val/.initial, 23/.@val/.initial, 34/.@val/.initial,
  04/.@val/.initial, 02/.@val/.initial, 03/.@val/.initial, 13/.@val/.initial,
  14/.@val/.initial, 24/.@val/.initial,
  012/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  013/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  014/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  023/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  024/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  034/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  123/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  124/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  134/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  234/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  0123/.@val/.initial,
  0124/.@val/.initial,
  0134/.@val/.initial,
  0234/.@val/.initial,
  1234/.@val/.initial,
  01234/.@val/.initial,
  01/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}, 02/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1},
  03/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}, 04/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1},
  12/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}, 13/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1},
  14/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}, 23/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1},
  24/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}, 34/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1},
  012/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}, 013/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1},
  014/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}, 023/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1},
  024/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}, 034/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1},
  123/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}, 124/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1},
  134/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}, 234/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1},
  0123/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}, 0124/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1},
  0134/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}, 0234/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1},
  1234/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}, 01234/.code=\arrowstylecode{#1}
}

% Macros to draw 2-cells.

\def\pent@abc{%
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/012] (198:0.45) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/012] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/012}} (198:0.8);
}
\def\pent@bcd{%
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/123] (126:0.45) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/123] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/123}} (126:0.8);
}
\def\pent@cde{%
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/234] (54:0.45) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/234] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/234}} (54:0.8);
}
\def\pent@ade{%
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/034] (-40:0.6) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/034] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/034}} (-5:0.5);
}
\def\pent@abe{%014
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/014] (-70:0.55) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/014] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/014}} (-110:0.55);
}
\def\pent@acd{%
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/023] (55:0.3) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/023] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/023}} (125:0.3);
}
\def\pent@bde{%
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/134] (-5:0.4) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/134] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/134}} (35:0.5);
}
\def\pent@ace{%
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/024] (-45:0.45) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/024] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/024}} (-45:0.1);
}
\def\pent@abd{%
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/013] (-90:0.22) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/013] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/013}} (-150:0.46);
}
\def\pent@bce{%
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/124] (188:0.4) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/124] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/124}} (150:0.55);
}

% Macro to draw a single pentagonal node.

\def\pent@#1#2{
  \begin{scope}[shift=#2, commutative diagrams/every diagram]

    \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4} {
      \tikzmath{\a = 270 - (72 * \i);}
      \node (n{#1}\i) at (\a:1) {
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/\i}};
    }

    \node (p#1) at (0,0) [circle, inner sep = 0pt,
    fit = (n{#1}0.center)(n{#1}1.center)(n{#1}2.center)
          (n{#1}3.center)(n{#1}4.center)] {};

    \begin{scope}[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow, every label]
      \ifcase #1
      \def\list{0/1, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 0/4, 0/2, 0/3}\or
      \def\list{0/1, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 0/4, 1/3, 1/4}\or
      \def\list{0/1, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 0/4, 0/2, 2/4}\or
      \def\list{0/1, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 0/4, 0/3, 1/3}\or
      \def\list{0/1, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 0/4, 1/4, 2/4}\else
      \def\list{}\fi

      \foreach \s / \e in \list {
        \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/\s\e] (n{#1}\s) --
          node [/pentagon/labelstyle/\s\e] {
          \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/\s\e}} (n{#1}\e);
      }

      \ifcase #1
      \pent@abc\pent@acd\pent@ade\or
      \pent@bcd\pent@bde\pent@abe\or
      \pent@cde\pent@ace\pent@abc\or
      \pent@ade\pent@abd\pent@bcd\or
      \pent@abe\pent@bce\pent@cde
      \else\fi

    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
}

% The pentagon of pentagons macro itself.
%
% This is the only user callable macro provided here.
%
% Takes a single parameter consisting of a list of key value pairs. These are
% processed using the keys mechanism (pgfkeys) built into TikZ, so they follow
% a familiar format.
%
% /pentagon/label/XXX = ....      Set code to typeset label of arrow XXX
% /pentagon/arrowstyle/XXX = ...  Set TikZ format for typesetting of arrow XXX.
%                                 Overrides default.
% /pentagon/labelstyle/XXX = ...  Set TikZ format for typesetting of label on
%                                 arrow XXX. Overrides default.
%
% Here XXX denotes a sequence of integers identifying a generating cell by
% listing the numbers of the vertices (in order) of the corresponding face of
% the 4-simplex.
%
% You may use the path setting mechanism of pgfkeys to avoid too much path noise
% in a key value list. For example:
%
%   \pentagon{/pentagon/label/.cd,
%     0=$0$, 1=$1$, 2=$2$, 3=$3$, 4=$4$,
%     01=$a$, 12=$b$, 23=$c$, 34=$d$, 04=$e$,
%     02=$f$, 03=$g$, 13=$h$, 14=$k$, 24=$l$,
%     012=$\alpha$, 034=$\beta$, 023=$\gamma$, 123=$\delta$, 134=$\epsilon$,
%     014=$\zeta$, 024=$\eta$, 234=$\theta$, 013=$\iota$, 124=$\kappa$,
%     0123=$\Theta$, 0124=$\Phi$, 0134=$\Psi$, 0234=$\Lambda$, 1234=$\Pi$,
%     01234=$\mathcal{F}$}
%

\def\pentagon#1{
  \pgfkeys{#1}
  \pent@{2}{(270:3)}\pent@{0}{(198:3)}\pent@{3}{(126:3)}
  \pent@{1}{(54:3)}\pent@{4}{(342:3)}

  \begin{scope}[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow, every label]
    \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/0123] (p0) --
    node [/pentagon/labelstyle/0123] {
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/0123}} (p3);

    \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/0134] (p3) --
    node [/pentagon/labelstyle/0134] {
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/0134}} (p1);

    \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/1234] (p1) --
    node [/pentagon/labelstyle/1234] {
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/1234}} (p4);

    \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/0234] (p0) --
    node [/pentagon/labelstyle/0234] {
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/0234}} (p2);

    \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/0124] (p2) --
    node [/pentagon/labelstyle/0124] {
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/0124}} (p4);

    \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/01234] (270:0.75) --
    node [/pentagon/labelstyle/01234] {
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/01234}} (90:0.75);
  \end{scope}
}

\makeatother
```

**Problem.** While square and pent work perfectly together, when I use pent and squares in the same master file something clashes and the drawing of the square or of the pentagon (according to the one I call first in the master file) becomes strange; more precisely, the label positioning gets messed up. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% Option, used to get squiggly arrows in example.
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \input{squares}
    \input{pent}
%
\noindent Symmetric square
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \squares{
                /squares/label/.cd,
                01=$f$, 12=$g$, 23=$h$, 03=$i$, 02=$j$, 13=$k$,
                012=$\beta$, 023=$\alpha$, 123=$\delta$, 013=$\gamma$,
                0123=$\Gamma$
            }
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
        Pentagon
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.1]
            \pentagon{
                /pentagon/label/.cd,
                01=$f$, 12=$g$, 23=$h$, 34=$i$, 04=$j$, 02=$k$, 03=$l$,
                13=$m$, 14=$n$, 24=$o$,
                012=$\alpha$, 023=$\beta$, 034=$\gamma$,
                024=$\delta$, 234=$\epsilon$, 014=$\zeta$,
                124=$\eta$, 123=$\theta$, 013=$\iota$,
                134=$\lambda$,
                0234=$A$, 0123=$C$, 0124=$B$,
                0134=$D$, 1234=$E$, 01234=$\Theta$
            }
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is obvious *why* that happens: both files have a definition `\def\labelstylecode`, but these definitions do not coincide. You should replace *all* instances of `\labelstylecode` in, say, `pent.tex` by `\labelstylecode@pent`, say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `\def\labelstylecode` and `\def\arrowstylecode` appear in different files, and the definitions do not coincide. To fix this, define a version of each of these macros for each file individually.

In more detail, call this `squares.tex`:

```
\makeatletter

% Setup keys for squares macro.
% Used to specify:
% - Labels for arrows.
% - Styles for labels and arrows.

\def\labelstylecode@square#1{%
  \pgfkeys@split@path%
  \edef\label@key{/squares/label/\pgfkeyscurrentname}%
  \edef\style@key{\pgfkeyscurrentkey/.@val}%
  \def\temp@a{#1}%
  \def\temp@b{\pgfkeysnovalue}%
  \ifx\temp@a\temp@b
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{\label@key}\temp@a
    \ifx\temp@a\temp@b\else
      \pgfkeysalso{commutative diagrams/.cd, \style@key}%
    \fi
  \else
    \pgfkeys{\style@key/.code = \pgfkeysalso{#1}}%
  \fi}
\def\arrowstylecode@square#1{%
  \edef\style@key{\pgfkeyscurrentkey/.@val}%
  \def\temp@a{#1}%
  \def\temp@b{\pgfkeysnovalue}%
  \ifx\temp@a\temp@b
    \pgfkeysalso{commutative diagrams/.cd, \style@key}%
  \else
    \pgfkeys{\style@key/.code = \pgfkeysalso{#1}}%
  \fi}

% Don't change these defaults here. These can be changed locally in the
% key-value list provided in a call to the morphism of squaress macro.

\pgfkeys{
  /squares/label/.cd,
  0/.initial = {$\bullet$}, 1/.initial = {$\bullet$}, 2/.initial = {$\bullet$},
  3/.initial = {$\bullet$},
  01/.initial, 12/.initial, 23/.initial,
  02/.initial, 03/.initial, 13/.initial,
  012/.initial, 013/.initial, 023/.initial, 123/.initial,
  0123/.initial,
  /squares/labelstyle/.cd,
  01/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap},
  12/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap},
  23/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap},
  03/.@val/.initial,
  02/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{description},
  13/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{description},
  012/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{above left = -1pt and -1pt},
  013/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap, right},
  023/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{left},
  123/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap, above right = -1pt and -1pt},
  0123/.@val/.initial,
  01/.code=\labelstylecode@square{#1}, 02/.code=\labelstylecode@square{#1},
  03/.code=\labelstylecode@square{#1}, 12/.code=\labelstylecode@square{#1},
  13/.code=\labelstylecode@square{#1}, 23/.code=\labelstylecode@square{#1},
  012/.code=\labelstylecode@square{#1}, 013/.code=\labelstylecode@square{#1},
  023/.code=\labelstylecode@square{#1}, 123/.code=\labelstylecode@square{#1},
  0123/.code=\labelstylecode@square{#1},
  /squares/arrowstyle/.cd,
  01/.@val/.initial, 12/.@val/.initial, 23/.@val/.initial,
  02/.@val/.initial, 03/.@val/.initial, 13/.@val/.initial,
  012/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  013/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  023/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  123/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  0123/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  01/.code=\arrowstylecode@square{#1}, 02/.code=\arrowstylecode@square{#1},
  03/.code=\arrowstylecode@square{#1}, 12/.code=\arrowstylecode@square{#1},
  13/.code=\arrowstylecode@square{#1}, 23/.code=\arrowstylecode@square{#1},
  012/.code=\arrowstylecode@square{#1}, 013/.code=\arrowstylecode@square{#1},
  023/.code=\arrowstylecode@square{#1}, 123/.code=\arrowstylecode@square{#1},
  0123/.code=\arrowstylecode@square{#1}
}

% Macros to draw 2-cells.

\def\sqs@abc{%
  \draw [/squares/arrowstyle/012] (235:0.25) --
  node [/squares/labelstyle/012] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/squares/label/012}} (235:0.6);
}
\def\sqs@bcd{%
  \draw [/squares/arrowstyle/123] (-54:0.25) --
  node [/squares/labelstyle/123] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/squares/label/123}} (-54:0.6);
}
\def\sqs@acd{%
  \draw [/squares/arrowstyle/023] (55:0.55) --
  node [/squares/labelstyle/023] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/squares/label/023}} (15:0.45);
}
\def\sqs@abd{%
  \draw [/squares/arrowstyle/013] (125:0.55) --
  node [/squares/labelstyle/013] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/squares/label/013}} (165:0.45);
}


% Macro to draw a single squares node.

\def\sqs@#1#2{
  \begin{scope}[shift=#2, commutative diagrams/every diagram]

    \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3} {
      \tikzmath{\a = 135 + (90 * \i);}
      \node (n{#1}\i) at (\a:1) {
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/squares/label/\i}};
    }

    \node (s#1) at (0,0) [circle, inner sep = 0pt,
    fit = (n{#1}0.center)(n{#1}1.center)(n{#1}2.center)
          (n{#1}3.center)] {};

    \begin{scope}[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow, every label]
      \ifcase #1
      \def\list{0/1, 1/2, 2/3, 0/2, 0/3}\or
      \def\list{0/1, 1/2, 2/3, 1/3, 0/3}\else
      \def\list{}\fi

      \foreach \s / \e in \list {
        \draw [/squares/arrowstyle/\s\e] (n{#1}\s) --
          node [/squares/labelstyle/\s\e] {
          \pgfkeysvalueof{/squares/label/\s\e}} (n{#1}\e);
      }

      \ifcase #1
      \sqs@abc\sqs@acd\or
      \sqs@abd\sqs@bcd
      \else\fi

    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
}

% The 3-simplex macro itself.
%
% This is the only user callable macro provided here.
%
% Takes a single parameter consisting of a list of key value pairs. These are
% processed using the keys mechanism (pgfkeys) built into TikZ, so they follow
% a familiar format.
%
% /squares/label/XXX = ....      Set code to typeset label of arrow XXX
% /squares/arrowstyle/XXX = ...  Set TikZ format for typesetting of arrow XXX.
%                                 Overrides default.
% /squares/labelstyle/XXX = ...  Set TikZ format for typesetting of label on
%                                 arrow XXX. Overrides default.
%
% Here XXX denotes a sequence of integers identifying a generating cell by
% listing the numbers of the vertices (in order) of the corresponding face of
% the 4-simplex.
%
% You may use the path setting mechanism of pgfkeys to avoid too much path noise
% in a key value list. For example:
%
%   \squares{/squares/label/.cd,
%     0=$0$, 1=$1$, 2=$2$, 3=$3$,
%     01=$a$, 12=$b$, 23=$c$, 02=$f$, 03=$g$, 13=$h$,
%     012=$\alpha$, 023=$\beta$, 123=$\gamma$, 013=$\delta$,
%     0123=$\mathcal{F}$}
%

\def\squares#1{
  \pgfkeys{#1}
  \sqs@{0}{(180:1.8)}\sqs@{1}{(0:1.8)}

  \begin{scope}[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow, every label]
    \draw [shorten >=10pt, shorten <=10pt, /squares/arrowstyle/0123] (s0) --
    node [/squares/labelstyle/0123] {%
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/squares/label/0123}} (s1);

  \end{scope}
}

\makeatother
```

and this `pent.tex`:

```
\makeatletter

% Setup keys for pentagon macro.
% Used to specify:
% - Labels for arrows.
% - Styles for labels and arrows.

\def\labelstylecode@pent#1{%
  \pgfkeys@split@path%
  \edef\label@key{/pentagon/label/\pgfkeyscurrentname}%
  \edef\style@key{\pgfkeyscurrentkey/.@val}%
  \def\temp@a{#1}%
  \def\temp@b{\pgfkeysnovalue}%
  \ifx\temp@a\temp@b
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{\label@key}\temp@a
    \ifx\temp@a\temp@b\else
      \pgfkeysalso{commutative diagrams/.cd, \style@key}%
    \fi
  \else
    \pgfkeys{\style@key/.code = \pgfkeysalso{#1}}%
  \fi}
\def\arrowstylecode@pent#1{%
  \edef\style@key{\pgfkeyscurrentkey/.@val}%
  \def\temp@a{#1}%
  \def\temp@b{\pgfkeysnovalue}%
  \ifx\temp@a\temp@b
    \pgfkeysalso{commutative diagrams/.cd, \style@key}%
  \else
    \pgfkeys{\style@key/.code = \pgfkeysalso{#1}}%
  \fi}

% Don't change these defaults here. These can be changed locally in the
% key-value list provided in a call to the pentagon of pentagons macro.

\pgfkeys{
  /pentagon/label/.cd,
  0/.initial = {$\bullet$}, 1/.initial = {$\bullet$}, 2/.initial = {$\bullet$},
  3/.initial = {$\bullet$}, 4/.initial = {$\bullet$},
  01/.initial, 12/.initial, 23/.initial, 34/.initial, 04/.initial,
  02/.initial, 03/.initial, 13/.initial, 14/.initial, 24/.initial,
  012/.initial, 013/.initial, 014/.initial, 023/.initial, 024/.initial,
  034/.initial, 123/.initial, 124/.initial, 134/.initial, 234/.initial,
  0123/.initial, 0124/.initial, 0134/.initial, 0234/.initial, 1234/.initial,
  01234/.initial,
  /pentagon/labelstyle/.cd,
  01/.@val/.initial, 12/.@val/.initial, 23/.@val/.initial, 34/.@val/.initial,
  04/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap},
  02/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{description},
  03/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{description},
  13/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{description},
  14/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{description},
  24/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{description},
  012/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap, above},
  013/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{below = 1pt},
  014/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{below},
  023/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap, above = 1pt},
  024/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{below left = -1pt and -1pt},
  034/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap, right},
  123/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{below left = -1pt and -1pt},
  124/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap, right},
  134/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{left},
  234/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap, below right = -1pt and -1pt},
  0123/.@val/.initial,
  0124/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap},
  0134/.@val/.initial,
  0234/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{swap},
  1234/.@val/.initial,
  01234/.@val/.initial,
  01/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1}, 02/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1},
  03/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1}, 04/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1},
  12/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1}, 13/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1},
  14/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1}, 23/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1},
  24/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1}, 34/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1},
  012/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1}, 013/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1},
  014/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1}, 023/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1},
  024/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1}, 034/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1},
  123/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1}, 124/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1},
  134/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1}, 234/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1},
  0123/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1}, 0124/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1},
  0134/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1}, 0234/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1},
  1234/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1}, 01234/.code=\labelstylecode@pent{#1},
  /pentagon/arrowstyle/.cd,
  01/.@val/.initial, 12/.@val/.initial, 23/.@val/.initial, 34/.@val/.initial,
  04/.@val/.initial, 02/.@val/.initial, 03/.@val/.initial, 13/.@val/.initial,
  14/.@val/.initial, 24/.@val/.initial,
  012/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  013/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  014/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  023/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  024/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  034/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  123/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  124/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  134/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  234/.@val/.initial=\pgfkeysalso{Rightarrow},
  0123/.@val/.initial,
  0124/.@val/.initial,
  0134/.@val/.initial,
  0234/.@val/.initial,
  1234/.@val/.initial,
  01234/.@val/.initial,
  01/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1}, 02/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1},
  03/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1}, 04/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1},
  12/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1}, 13/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1},
  14/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1}, 23/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1},
  24/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1}, 34/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1},
  012/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1}, 013/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1},
  014/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1}, 023/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1},
  024/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1}, 034/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1},
  123/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1}, 124/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1},
  134/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1}, 234/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1},
  0123/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1}, 0124/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1},
  0134/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1}, 0234/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1},
  1234/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1}, 01234/.code=\arrowstylecode@pent{#1}
}

% Macros to draw 2-cells.

\def\pent@abc{%
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/012] (198:0.45) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/012] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/012}} (198:0.8);
}
\def\pent@bcd{%
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/123] (126:0.45) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/123] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/123}} (126:0.8);
}
\def\pent@cde{%
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/234] (54:0.45) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/234] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/234}} (54:0.8);
}
\def\pent@ade{%
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/034] (-40:0.6) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/034] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/034}} (-5:0.5);
}
\def\pent@abe{%014
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/014] (-70:0.55) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/014] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/014}} (-110:0.55);
}
\def\pent@acd{%
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/023] (55:0.3) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/023] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/023}} (125:0.3);
}
\def\pent@bde{%
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/134] (-5:0.4) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/134] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/134}} (35:0.5);
}
\def\pent@ace{%
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/024] (-45:0.45) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/024] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/024}} (-45:0.1);
}
\def\pent@abd{%
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/013] (-90:0.22) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/013] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/013}} (-150:0.46);
}
\def\pent@bce{%
  \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/124] (188:0.4) --
  node [/pentagon/labelstyle/124] {
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/124}} (150:0.55);
}

% Macro to draw a single pentagonal node.

\def\pent@#1#2{
  \begin{scope}[shift=#2, commutative diagrams/every diagram]

    \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4} {
      \tikzmath{\a = 270 - (72 * \i);}
      \node (n{#1}\i) at (\a:1) {
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/\i}};
    }

    \node (p#1) at (0,0) [circle, inner sep = 0pt,
    fit = (n{#1}0.center)(n{#1}1.center)(n{#1}2.center)
          (n{#1}3.center)(n{#1}4.center)] {};

    \begin{scope}[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow, every label]
      \ifcase #1
      \def\list{0/1, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 0/4, 0/2, 0/3}\or
      \def\list{0/1, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 0/4, 1/3, 1/4}\or
      \def\list{0/1, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 0/4, 0/2, 2/4}\or
      \def\list{0/1, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 0/4, 0/3, 1/3}\or
      \def\list{0/1, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 0/4, 1/4, 2/4}\else
      \def\list{}\fi

      \foreach \s / \e in \list {
        \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/\s\e] (n{#1}\s) --
          node [/pentagon/labelstyle/\s\e] {
          \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/\s\e}} (n{#1}\e);
      }

      \ifcase #1
      \pent@abc\pent@acd\pent@ade\or
      \pent@bcd\pent@bde\pent@abe\or
      \pent@cde\pent@ace\pent@abc\or
      \pent@ade\pent@abd\pent@bcd\or
      \pent@abe\pent@bce\pent@cde
      \else\fi

    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
}

% The pentagon of pentagons macro itself.
%
% This is the only user callable macro provided here.
%
% Takes a single parameter consisting of a list of key value pairs. These are
% processed using the keys mechanism (pgfkeys) built into TikZ, so they follow
% a familiar format.
%
% /pentagon/label/XXX = ....      Set code to typeset label of arrow XXX
% /pentagon/arrowstyle/XXX = ...  Set TikZ format for typesetting of arrow XXX.
%                                 Overrides default.
% /pentagon/labelstyle/XXX = ...  Set TikZ format for typesetting of label on
%                                 arrow XXX. Overrides default.
%
% Here XXX denotes a sequence of integers identifying a generating cell by
% listing the numbers of the vertices (in order) of the corresponding face of
% the 4-simplex.
%
% You may use the path setting mechanism of pgfkeys to avoid too much path noise
% in a key value list. For example:
%
%   \pentagon{/pentagon/label/.cd,
%     0=$0$, 1=$1$, 2=$2$, 3=$3$, 4=$4$,
%     01=$a$, 12=$b$, 23=$c$, 34=$d$, 04=$e$,
%     02=$f$, 03=$g$, 13=$h$, 14=$k$, 24=$l$,
%     012=$\alpha$, 034=$\beta$, 023=$\gamma$, 123=$\delta$, 134=$\epsilon$,
%     014=$\zeta$, 024=$\eta$, 234=$\theta$, 013=$\iota$, 124=$\kappa$,
%     0123=$\Theta$, 0124=$\Phi$, 0134=$\Psi$, 0234=$\Lambda$, 1234=$\Pi$,
%     01234=$\mathcal{F}$}
%

\def\pentagon#1{
  \pgfkeys{#1}
  \pent@{2}{(270:3)}\pent@{0}{(198:3)}\pent@{3}{(126:3)}
  \pent@{1}{(54:3)}\pent@{4}{(342:3)}

  \begin{scope}[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow, every label]
    \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/0123] (p0) --
    node [/pentagon/labelstyle/0123] {
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/0123}} (p3);

    \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/0134] (p3) --
    node [/pentagon/labelstyle/0134] {
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/0134}} (p1);

    \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/1234] (p1) --
    node [/pentagon/labelstyle/1234] {
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/1234}} (p4);

    \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/0234] (p0) --
    node [/pentagon/labelstyle/0234] {
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/0234}} (p2);

    \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/0124] (p2) --
    node [/pentagon/labelstyle/0124] {
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/0124}} (p4);

    \draw [/pentagon/arrowstyle/01234] (270:0.75) --
    node [/pentagon/labelstyle/01234] {
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pentagon/label/01234}} (90:0.75);
  \end{scope}
}

\makeatother
```

Now compiling your file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%
\input{squares}
\input{pent}
\begin{document}
%
\noindent Symmetric square
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \squares{
                /squares/label/.cd,
                01=$f$, 12=$g$, 23=$h$, 03=$i$, 02=$j$, 13=$k$,
                012=$\beta$, 023=$\alpha$, 123=$\delta$, 013=$\gamma$,
                0123=$\Gamma$
            }
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
        Pentagon
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.1]
            \pentagon{
                /pentagon/label/.cd,
                01=$f$, 12=$g$, 23=$h$, 34=$i$, 04=$j$, 02=$k$, 03=$l$,
                13=$m$, 14=$n$, 24=$o$,
                012=$\alpha$, 023=$\beta$, 034=$\gamma$,
                024=$\delta$, 234=$\epsilon$, 014=$\zeta$,
                124=$\eta$, 123=$\theta$, 013=$\iota$,
                134=$\lambda$,
                0234=$A$, 0123=$C$, 0124=$B$,
                0134=$D$, 1234=$E$, 01234=$\Theta$
            }
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Note that may not be the right person for follow-up questions on some details of these codes. I am also not sure if it is appropriate to exchange codes with so many lines on this site, but as long as it does not make the posts exceed the limits it could be OK.